# error: expected primary-expression before ')' when passing function-pointer to a function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers

Following is the function that takes function prototype as an argument:

```
void callAdded(void (*unitAdded)(rates));
```

When I do:

```
callAdded((&ConverterProxy::unitAdded)(rates));
```

`ConverterProxy::unitAdded` is a static function and `rates` is a `struct`.

Why do I get that error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be ok with just `callAdded(&ConverterProxy::unitAdded);`, assuming there's only one overload with that name. Otherwise you have to cast to the right function type - the syntax you're trying to use just doesn't exist.